# Python 3.x: Merge two dictionaries with same keys and values being array

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Python version: 3.x

I have two dictionaries with same keys and the values are arrays. Most of the questions I saw here, for the required purpose, have only one value for each key. What I want is to merge those two dictionaries with values as joined array. Maybe below would clear:

What I've:

```
d1 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([2.5, 4.5, 7.5, 9.5]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([10.5, 11.7, 12.3, 15.0])}
d2 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([15.6, 20, 23, 27])}
```

I've tried:

```
d3 = {**d1, **d2}
```

What I want:

```
d3 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([2.5, 4.5, 7.5, 9.5, 10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([10.5, 11.7, 12.3, 15.0, 15.6, 20, 23, 27])}
```

Am I missing something here? Please help!

P.S: I've looked at [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

Comment: Does every key appear exactly once in both dicts?

Comment: Yes, the keys are unique and same for dictionaries. However the number of values for each same key might defer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> d1 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([2.5, 4.5, 7.5, 9.5]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([10.5, 11.7, 12.3, 15.0])}
> >>> d2 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array([10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8]), (1, "Spring"): np.array([15.6, 20, 23, 27])}
> >>> d3 = {k: np.concatenate((d1.get(k, np.array([])), d2.get(k, np.array([])))) for k in set(d1.keys()).union(set(d2.keys()))}
> >>> d3
> {(1, 'Spring'): array([10.5, 11.7, 12.3, 15. , 15.6, 20. , 23. , 27. ]), (1, 'Autumn'): array([ 2.5,  4.5,  7.5,  9.5, 10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8])}
> ```

**Notes**:

- It's a *dict* comprehension
- First, a union of the keys in the 2 *dict*s is computed, to make sure that no key is left aside (for that, the keys in each *dict* are converted into a *set*)
- For each element in the above set, get the corresponding array (empty one if the key is not present) from each *dict*, and concatenate them
- This is the *Python*ic (and also **general**) approach, my *numpy* knowledge is somewhere close to ***0*** (I'm sure that it's pretty obvious from the code snippet - it looks awfully complex with all those parentheses), it's extremely likely that *numpy* has something to make things in a much more elegant manner
- [[SO]: How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) desired output and the current one (considering that the *dict* values are simply iterables (whether they are *Python* or *numpy* or any other kind is irrelevant)) are 2 different (and equally correct) approaches of the ***merge*** concept regarding *dict*s, in case of common keys:

  - One only keeps the value from the last *dict*
  - The other sums (whatever *sum* would mean for the operands) all of them

Comment: Thank you, glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 4):

If you always have the same keys in both dicts, this should fit your needs:

```
d3 = {key:np.hstack([d1[key],d2[key]]) for key in d1.keys()}
```

Outputs:

```
In [7]: d3
Out[7]: 
{(1, 'Autumn'): array([ 2.5,  4.5,  7.5,  9.5, 10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8]),
 (1, 'Spring'): array([10.5, 11.7, 12.3, 15. , 15.6, 20. , 23. , 27. ])}
```

But this relies on the assumption, that for every key there is a value and that every key appears in both dicts.

Comment: Thanks! It also relies on array dimensions. `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`. Upvote, since most of the dictionaries I'm working on have same dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need smth like:

```
{key:np.append(d1[key], d2[key]) for key in d1.keys()}
```

Not sure about np.append though.
And, of course, it will work only if dicts have the same keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

d1 = {(1, "Autumn"): [2.5, 4.5, 7.5, 9.5], (1, "Spring"): [10.5, 11.7, 12.3, 15.0]}
d2 = {(1, "Autumn"): [10.2, 13.3, 15.7, 18.8], (1, "Spring"): [15.6, 20, 23, 27]}
d3 = {(1, "Autumn"): np.array(d1[(1, "Autumn")] + d2[(1, "Autumn")]), (1,"Spring"): np.array(d1[(1, "Spring")] + d2[(1, "Spring")])}
```

I used the `np.array()` in the end because there is difference between lists and numpy arrays. When you use the `A + B` in numpy, each element of the A added to the array other element of the B. On the other hand, when use `A+B` where A and B are lists, they join each other.

Comment: This will for sure work for the above example. But it's good too not individually sum by  keys. upvote.